# Why do browsers support implicit function properties on objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, v8, spidermonkey

```
var obj = {
    foo: function() { return "this is foo"; },
    bar() { return "this is bar"; }
}
```

Executing this in NodeJS leads yields a SyntaxError at bar`^`( on line 3 - as would be expected.

Chrome and Firefox seem to be perfectly happy though, with what seems to be obviously wrong:

```
console.log(obj.foo()); // "this is foo"
console.log(obj.bar()); // "this is bar"
```

Why do browser engines support this syntax? Is there documentation on this behaviour?

Comment: It's new ES6 syntax for object literals, try adding  `--harmony` to node and it will work too.

Comment: thank you, makes perfect sense now - time to read up on ES6 :)

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by jcubic, ES6 syntax is the answer.
Specifically, the *Object Literal Extensions*.

Here is a snippet from [Kyle Simpson](https://github.com/getify)'s great [YDKJS series](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS).

> **Object Literal Extensions** ([source](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/ch2.md#object-literal-extensions))
>
> ES6 adds a number of important convenience extensions to the humble `{
>   .. }` object literal.
>
> **Concise Properties**
>
> You're certainly familiar with declaring object literals in this form:
>
> ```
> var x = 2, y = 3,
>     o = {
>         x: x,
>         y: y
>     };
> ```
>
> If it's always felt redundant to say x: x all over, there's good news.
>   If you need to define a property that is the same name as a lexical
>   identifier, you can shorten it from x: x to x. Consider:
>
> ```
> var x = 2, y = 3,
>     o = {
>         x,
>         y
>     };
> ```
>
> **Concise Methods** ([source](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20&%20beyond/ch2.md#concise-methods))
>
> In a similar spirit to concise properties we just examined, functions
>   attached to properties in object literals also have a concise form,
>   for convenience.
>
> The old way:
>
> ```
> var o = {
>     x: function(){
>         // ..
>     },
>     y: function(){
>         // ..
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> And as of ES6:
>
> ```
> var o = {
>     x() {
>         // ..
>     },
>     y() {
>         // ..
>     }
> }
> ```